Sudo privileges without access to others home dir - Debian Linux Server
I'm new to Linux server management and I have a small Debian server.
I want some users to have sudo privileges such as installing a new package and etc. but I don't want them to be able to access or change some specific directories such as other people's home directory and my backup directory.
I am a sudoer as well but I want their access to be different than my access.
I want to have the full sudo privileges but I want their users to be able to use all sudo privileges except the ones I put in a blacklist and also they should not be able to access some specific directories.
I would appreciate it if you could guide me through the process of how to do these as I'm not that familiar with Linux commands in these problems.

set in sudoers explicitly the command you permit them to run

I was thinking of adding a new user group or something similar to sudo but with less access. because I want their access to be different than my access and I'm a sudoer as well. I want my user to be able to use all sudo privileges, but other users only have access to the sudo commands that are not in blacklist. also they should not be able to visit some specific directories.

You can create groups in sudoers and there define "privileges" per group.

"but other users only have access to the sudo commands that are not in blacklist" – This won't work.

how can I create groups in sudoers with different privileges? @RomeoNinov
Also, thanks Kamil. Right now, I'm only looking for a way to restrict access to specific directories.

@CryptoRythmer, restrict them to run only short list of command. With directory the things need different approach
